# Changing method to static after calling it with the double colon in class in PHP

Tags: php, class

I have piece of code:

```
class example {
    public function say($x) {
        if ($x > 0) {
            echo $x;
            $this->say($x - 1);
        }
        else echo "0<br>\n";
    }
}

example::say(5);
```

Calling it I have:

```
 5
 Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in (...).php on line 5
```

Why is this happening? What is happening to function 'say'? I see it's called once from outside a class, but why inside class PHP claims 'say' isn't accesible by '$this->'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is actually pretty clear: You cannot use $this, as you never created an instance of your example class. If you want to call your method statically, use this:

```
class example {
    public static function say($x) {
        if ($x > 0) {
           echo $x;
           self::say($x - 1); // static call
       }
       else {
           echo "0<br>\n";
       }
   }
}

example::say(5);
```

Or in a more object oriented way:

```
class example {
    public function say($x) {
        if ($x > 0) {
           echo $x;
           $this->say($x - 1);
       }
       else {
           echo "0<br>\n";
       }
   }
}

$x = new example();
$x->say(5);
```

You *can* call a non-static method statically, but you *shouldn't* (and this will only work if the method does not use $this). This is why PHP warns you if E_STRICT is enabled

Answer (score 2):

Use `self::say()` or `example::say()`. `$this` should be used if you're in the object context (i.e. you have an example object instantiated with `new`).

Comment: What if after
    example::say(5);
I want to do
    $sth = new example();
    #sth->say(6);
In my class it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the [Scope Resolution Operator](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) (::) to access the static methods within the class. As such, change line 5 to read...

```
example::say($x - 1);
```

(You could also use `self:say` to the same effect.)

Comment: or to self::say($x - 1)l but how can I have this as non-static and and calling it as static?

Comment: @Kuba Werlos You can't have a non-static method called statically - what object instance would it call?

Comment: Why?
    class example2 {
        public function foo($x) {
                echo $x;
        }
    }

    example2::foo('hello');
This works fine

Comment: @Kuba Werlos If you run that code against PHP in strict mode you'll get a "Non-static method example2::foo() should not be called statically" warning. In other words, it's just letting you off the hook - it's still the wrong thing to do.